# How to return a promise in a function from the last promise in a chain of "then"

Tags: javascript, selenium, return, promise

I'm writing a test using Selenium and JavaScript. I'm new to both, and also new to functional programming and promises. I'm trying to create a function that needs to do 3 things:

1. Click on an input
2. Clear the input
3. SendKeys to input

My current function does not work:

```
    var clearAndSendKeys = function(driver, elementIdentifier, sendKeys) {
        var returnValue;
        driver.findElement(elementIdentifier).then(function(inputField){
            inputField.click().then(function() {
                inputField.clear().then(function() {
                    returnValue = inputField.sendKeys(sendKeys);
                });                 
            });                 
        });
        return returnValue;
    }
```

The function would then be called as for example:

```
    clearAndSendKeys(driver, webdriver.By.id('date_field'), '14.09.2015').then(function(){
        //Do stuff
    });
```

I expected the variable `returnValue` to contain the promise from `sendKeys`. However the function `clearAndSendKeys` returns the undefined variable before sendKeys is ran. I assume this is because `returnValue` was never defined as a promise, and so the program does not know that it needs to wait for `sendKeys`.

How can I make my function `clearAndSendKeys` return the promise from `sendKeys`? I'd rather avoid having to add a callback to the `clearAndSendKeys` function.

Edit: Removed `.then({return data})` from the code as this was a typo.

Comment: you need to assign returnValue to the promise, first line should be `var returnValue = driver.findElement(...`,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s2b0v8nu/1/ - use callbacks

Comment: Hi Arun, why should he use callbacks when trying to use promises?

Comment: are any/all of those functions ( `.findElement()` `.click()` `.clear()` and `.sendKeys()` ) even asynchronous? I'm guessing `sendKeys` at least returns a promise, do any of the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return each promise from the `.then` callback:

```
var clearAndSendKeys = function(driver, elementIdentifier, sendKeys) {
    return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier).then(function(inputField){
        return inputField.click().then(function() {
            return inputField.clear().then(function() {
                return inputField.sendKeys(sendKeys);
            });                 
        });                 
    });
}
```

The promise returned by `.then` will resolve to the same value as the value returned from the callback.

---

See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for why your current code does not work. Promises are **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 4):

First of all its probably not the best idea to nest promises, completely defeating their main purpose of eliminating callback hell. `then` callback can return `Thenable` object that allows to create nice chains of async operations.

In this case you just need to store reference to input field available as a result of the first async operation in the scope of the main function and then create chain of async operations that can be returned from this function.

```
var clearAndSendKeys = function(driver, elementIdentifier, sendKeys) {
    var inputFieldRef;
    return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier)
        .then(function(inputField){
            inputFieldRef = inputField;
            return inputField.click();
        }).then(function() {
            return inputFieldRef.clear();
        }).then(function() {
            return inputFieldRef.sendKeys(sendKeys);
        });
}
```

Comment: That global `inputFieldRef` variable is a particularly ugly way of [accessing previous promise results in a .then() chain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) though.

Comment: Better than the pyramid of of death below!! @Bergi - I for one am interested in how to overcome this ugliness, but can't really see how anything in the link you posted is any more elegant

Comment: @JaromandaX: Well ES7 async/await is *definitely* more elegant :-) Regardless, I don't think a second level of nesting (more is not necessary) is that bad, and it could easily be `driver.findElement(…).then(function(inputField) { return inputField.click().then(inputField.clear.bind(inputField)).then(inputField.sendKeys.bind(inputField, sendKeys)); })`

Comment: @Bergi - thanks for that. I agree, that's a good compromise between pyramid and outer scope var (not necessarily global)