# Making modular login function with selenium-webdriver and mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am trying to create a login function that I can use with mocha testing and selenium-webdriver for unit testing, since I have a bunch of things to do that start with "user logs in and..."

Below is my best shot, but when I run it, the console just logs

```
Already registered user logs in and sees homepage
  1) should work (it's red text)

Login an existing user
```

and then nothing happens and I have to control-C out of the process. My code was working *before* I went for this modular login implementation, so I'm sure that's where my problem is. Is there something I am missing here? I am also open to general critiques of how I went about making the `login` function, since I don't have that much experience with webdriver.

Below is my code. It's in one js file.

```
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-string'));
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var expect = chai.expect,
webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By;

// I want this to be a modular login function I can use multiple places
function login(driver) {
    test.describe('Login an existing user', function() {
        test.it('should work', function() {
            this.timeout(0);

            var email = 'myemail@test.com';
            var password = 'password';

            driver.get('http://localhost:9000');

            driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                expect(title).to.equal('my title');
            })
            .then(function() {
                // do login stuff and click login button
            });
            .then(function() {
                return driver;
            });
        });
    });
}

//an example of when I would use the login function
test.describe('Already registered user logs in and sees homepage', function() {
  test.it('should work', function() {

    this.timeout(0);
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();

    driver = login(driver)
    .then(function() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("relevant xpath")).click();
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: What did you see when you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `login` from inside `test.it`, you are effectively calling `describe` inside `it`, which is not allowed. **Mocha simply does not support calling `describe` or `it` from inside `it`.** Unfortunately, it does not try to detect such occurrence and scream about it. It just goes ahead and do whatever it does. I all cases it results in undefined behavior, like the behavior you observed. In most cases, the undefined behavior is erratic. I *very rare* cases, it happens to match the developer's expectations but that's due to chance, not design.

In your case, I'd just remove the calls to `test.describe` and `test.it` from inside `login`, and make sure to return a promise. You can keep the `expect` there. You won't be able to call `this.timeout(0)` inside `login`, however. Something like this:

```
function login(driver) {
    var email = 'myemail@test.com';
    var password = 'password';

    driver.get('http://localhost:9000');

    return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        expect(title).to.equal('my title');
    })
    .then(function() {
        // do login stuff and click login button
    })
    .then(function () {
        return driver;
    });
}
```

And modify your calling code to:

```
var promise = login(driver)
.then(function(driver) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("relevant xpath")).click();
});
```

You can do whatever you want to the promise, or nothing at all. However, `driver` is not itself a promise so setting `driver` to that value won't work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the `describe` behavior! If I have `driver=login(driver)` it works fine. But it I add `driver.then(etc)` after that, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. I thought webdrivers were promiseable?

Comment: Looks like you deleted your earlier comment just as I was posting mine. Anyhow, I've edited with an example. You should not get the error you report if you actually return a value from your function. See the `return` I added before `driver.getTitle()...`.

Comment: Also `this.timeout` is not a function. If you remove describe, then what is `this`?

Comment: True, it is not longer possible to call `this.timeout` from inside `login`. You could do `login.call(this, driver)` but it not particularly meaningful to set timeout to 0 and then set it to something else later. If you want to have a special timeout only for `login` you could call `login` from a `beforeEach` or `before` hook.

Comment: Adding that extra `return` fixed the then issue, but then after using the function with `driver=login(driver).then(function() {driver.findElement...` I have `driver.findElement` is not a function! How can I maintain the driver object?

Comment: I've edited again. `driver` is not a promise so setting it to a promise value won't work. You should review the documentation of Selenium.

Comment: Alright thank you, I get it now. Also I finally found a related question, in case anyone is interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565577/how-to-return-a-promise-in-a-function-from-the-last-promise-in-a-chain-of-then